# Node/Express Email + Token Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express

I'm wondering if any Node/Express gurus could give me a little advice on if the following scenario that I'm trying to achieve is possible. I think it is, I'm just a little unsure on the best-practise way to tackle the problem.

I'm currently in the process of building a small client that will be protected. To gain access to the following the following steps must occur:

1. Input name + email address in a form that then sends this data in an email to an admin.
2. The email will containing a prebuilt link containing query params of the data that was input into the field. The link will have an API URL prior to the query params.
3. When the link is clicked an API request will be performed that takes the query params (mainly the email address) and grants this email address access to the client for a specific period of time such as 2 hours.
4. The client will  go to subdomain.domain.com, enter their email address (which gets validated to check that an admin has approved the email address) and have access to the client for 2 hours. There will also be a timer with the remainding session length.

The majority of this I can take care of but I thought I'd give you an insight in to the full picture of what it is I'm trying to achieve. The part that I have queries about is section 3 and giving an email address access to the client for a specific period of time. I don't want any passwords to be involved so what is the most-secure, more-advisable solution to this? Would I have to use tokens?

I will be building the server-side using Express unless I strictly have to use Node for whatever reason.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When the admin approves the request, the api inserts a row into a db (mongo would be easy) which expires in 2 hours (or however long).  Next, when the user goes to the subdomain, they enter their email address.  Your express app checks if the email is in mongo.  If it is, they have access.  You can stick their email in a cookie and check it that way on future requests.